# How to get a list of pages (not posts) with specific tags?

Tags: pages, tags

I am using the [Pages with category and tag](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pages-with-category-and-tag/) plugin to assign tags and categories to pages. And now I would like to retrieve a list of items with specific tags associated with a page and can’t seem to get it to work.

The code I am using is as follows; kludged together from what I can find online for fetching posts based on tags like [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025941/117259). And please excuse the very much “development” roughness in place in this stuff for now:

```
<?php

$tags = get_the_tags();
print_r($tags);

$args = array(
    "numberposts" => 3,
    "post_type" => "page",
    "tax_query" => array(
        array(
            "taxonomy" => "page_tag",
            "field"    => "term_id",
            "terms"    => $tags
        )
    )
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );

print_r($pages);

?>
```

Comment: I would recommend running a `WP_Query` instead of `get_pages()` or `get_posts()`. The parameters are documented with lots of examples in WP Developer Resources: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, while `WP_Query` suggestion [posted in an earlier answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/412717/52852) *should* work for me, it wasn’t working as expected.

So I figured out how to do this using `get_posts` instead: Instinctively one would think to get pages one needs to use `get_pages` but (and this is the key) you can get pages via `get_posts` as well as long as `post_type` is set `page` in the arguments. I came to this conclusion when I realized that posts and pages are both stored in `wp_posts` so `post_type` should work and it indeed did work!

This is what finally worked for me; just change the `$tag` value to match the tag value you want to use:

```
<?php

$tags = array('TheTagName');

$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'tag' => $tags,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'post_type' => array( 'page' )
);

$query = get_posts( $args );

echo '<ul class="page-list subpages-page-list">';
foreach ( $query as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
   echo sprintf('<li class="page_item page-item-%d menu-item">', $post->ID);
   echo "<a href='" .$post->guid . "'>" . $post->post_title . "</a>";
   echo '</li>';
endforeach;
echo '</ul>';

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`get_pages()` is a valid function, but it doesn't have any parameters for getting pages with specific taxonomy terms assigned.

`WP_Query` will get posts of any type (such as Pages) and can query by taxonomy terms. If you don't want to look through your plugin's code to find out what it calls the Page Tag taxonomy, in wp-admin, go to Pages > Tags and look at the URL. You will have something like `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=thetaxonomyname` - `thetaxonomyname` is what you're looking for. It will be `post_tag` if it's regular Core tags but could be something different depending on the plugin. Once you know for sure what your taxonomy is called, you can plug that into the `tax_query` portion of `WP_Query`.

From OP's comment, the final code is

```
<?php
$pages = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'showposts' => -1,
        'tag' => 'thetaxonomyname',
        'meta_key' => 'date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' )
        
    )
);
print_r($pages);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just tried the following and it works well: `new WP_Query( array(
   'showposts' => -1,
   'tag' => 'thetaxonomyname',
   'meta_key' => 'date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' )
   )
);new WP_Query( array(
   'showposts' => -1,
   'tag' => 'thetaxonomyname',
   'meta_key' => 'date',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' )
   )
);`

Comment: Well, it looks like I figured out another way to handle this. That `WP_Query` example I posted didn’t work as expected; answer coming shortly.